# Python - Reading in txt file without formatted columns

Tags: python

So I have a .txt file I need to read in to Python, but the formatting is preventing me from using the simple pandas.read_csv function. The .txt file looks like this:

```
"giver_username_if_known", "N/A"

"in_test_set", false 

"number_of_downvotes_of_request_at_retrieval", 2 

"number_of_upvotes_of_request_at_retrieval", 6 

"post_was_edited", false 

"request_id", "t3_w5491" 

"request_number_of_comments_at_retrieval", 7 

"request_text", "I'm not in College, or a starving artist or anything like that. I've just been a bit unlucky lately."

"request_text_edit_aware", "I'm not in College, or a starving artist or anything like that. I've just been a bit unlucky lately. I'm a 36 year old single guy with a job. But rent, and other bills killed me this month." 

"request_title", "[Request] Ontario, Canada - On my 3rd of 5 days without food, and it's getting unbearable. Can anyone help?" 

"requester_account_age_in_days_at_request", 14.416875 

"requester_account_age_in_days_at_retrieval", 531.9697222222222 

"requester_days_since_first_post_on_raop_at_request", 0.0 

"requester_days_since_first_post_on_raop_at_retrieval", 517.5111805555556 

"requester_number_of_comments_at_request", 8 

"requester_number_of_comments_at_retrieval", 93 

"requester_number_of_comments_in_raop_at_request", 0 

"requester_number_of_comments_in_raop_at_retrieval", 4 

"requester_number_of_posts_at_request", 1 

"requester_number_of_posts_at_retrieval", 6 

"requester_number_of_posts_on_raop_at_request", 0 

"requester_number_of_posts_on_raop_at_retrieval", 2 

"requester_number_of_subreddits_at_request", 8 

"requester_received_pizza", true 

"requester_subreddits_at_request", {
  "AdviceAnimals" 
  "WTF" 
  "funny" 
  "gaming" 
  "movies" 
  "technology" 
  "todayilearned" 
  "videos"
    } 

%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%
```

And after each set of "%" there is another entry (5671 overall) with the same formatting. The first string in each line is the column name, and the following string/integer is the data entry. How do I extract the data following each column name?

Comment: you could use regex

Comment: Where is the code you have tried?

Comment: @Rakesh_K theres no code, just common knowledge. Thats why i left a comment, and not an answer....

Comment: *How* is the format preventing you from using `pandas.read_csv`? Where is your code - how doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

1) In your call to read_csv, add str=','.  This tells the parser what separates the column/data in each line.

2) Also in your call to read_csv, add comment="%%%%%".  This tells the parser that any line that starts with "%%%%%" is to be treated and as comment and ignored.